# inline jsdoc for return

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

I know how to inline types for parameters:

```
function foo(/**number*/theNum, /**string*/theText){}
```

But how do I describe the return type using this method?

I'm not talking about the way to do it above the function, like this:

```
/** this method takes too much space!
 * @returns {boolean}
*/
function foo(){ return false; }
```

I want to describe it inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#return-type-description):

```
function /** boolean */ foo(){ return false; }
```